# How to implement a 2d array of LinkedLists

Tags: java, arrays, generics, collections

I'm working on implementing an algorithm from a paper. The paper describes using a grid, where each grid square holds a linked list of integers that represent objects in that grid square.

I decided to implement this using `LinkedList<Integer>[][]`, which of course gives me a `generic array creation` error.

I can't think of a better way of representing the idea of a grid of linked lists. I also understand that using `LinkedList[][]` would compile but is bad practice as it is untyped. However, I would prefer not to use `ArrayList<ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>>` because that is unreadable, at least to me.

Is there a way around using an untyped `LinkedList` here? Or perhaps some other solution?

Comment: Do you need a LinkedList? Why not a 2D array? Also, why would you use an ArrayList with a nested LinkedList? why not one or the other?

Comment: Now I am curious, for which algorithm you need that for?

Comment: It's an algorithm for finding the nearest neighbors to a point in 2 dimensions. It splits the 2d plane into a grid, and each grid square has a list of points within it. It then does distance calculations only on the points in the grids closest to the search point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list version

```
List<List<List<Integer>>> grid;
```

is not unreadable. To access a grid square it's just

```
List<Integer> items = grid.get(x).get(y);
```

Not that tough on the brane.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, I suppose that's not that ugly. I'm going refactor to this.

Answer (score 2):

Bohemian's answer is on the mark. If you're using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), a possible alternative is to use an [`ArrayTable<Integer, Integer, List<Integer>>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayTable.html). From the documentation:

> Fixed-size [`Table`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) implementation backed by a two-dimensional array.
>
> The allowed row and column keys must be supplied when the table is
>   created. The table always contains a mapping for every row key /
>   column pair. The value corresponding to a given row and column is null
>   unless another value is provided.
>
> The table's size is constant: the product of the number of supplied
>   row keys and the number of supplied column keys. The remove and clear
>   methods are not supported by the table or its views. The
>   `erase(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)` and `eraseAll()` methods may
>   be used instead.

Here's an example of its usage:

```
private static final int NUM_ROWS = 20; //for example
private static final int NUM_COLS = 20; //

private static final ArrayTable<Integer, Integer, List<Integer>> TABLE =
        ArrayTable.create(
                Ranges.closed(1, NUM_ROWS).asSet(DiscreteDomains.integers()),
                Ranges.closed(1, NUM_COLS).asSet(DiscreteDomains.integers())
        );

public static List<Integer> getGridQuareList(int row, int col) {
    @Nullable List<Integer> list = TABLE.at(row, col);
    if (list == null) {
        list = Lists.newArrayList(); //or newLinkedList() if you insist
        TABLE.set(row, col, list);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the embedded `ArrayList`/`LinkedList`. What you can do to clean it up, since you know what kind of generic type they will have, is to wrap them inside some other class. Like so:

```
public class Grid {
    private List<List<List<Object>>> inner;

    public List<Object> objectsAtPosition(int x, int y) {
        return inner.get(x).get(y);
    }

    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why on earth you would need a 3 dimensional list (2d array of a list, considering ArrayLists is really a 3d list/array). But if you **do** need that, then you should use what @Bohemian wrote:

```
List<List<List<Integer>>> grid;
```

What you should consider:

Declare variables to interfaces, not implementations, eg.:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>
```

instead of

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>
```

Also, generally it's **not a good idea** to mix generics with arrays, it can get nasty. If you wan't to do it in java and that's what you need do it the java way, as the others stated:

```
List<List<List<Integer>>>
```

Comment: "considering ArrayLists is really a 3d list/array" Sorry, I'm a bit confused about this part of your answer.

Comment: A 2 dimensional array of lists, if you use ArrayLists, is (by interface) List<List<List<Object>>> which is a 3d list. (Also a 3d array if you use ArrayLists.) edit: If you consider a List to be a one dimensional List (as you should) then having a 2d array of them is a 3d list. And I mentioned ArrayLists because they can be used as arrays and/or lists, so it doesn't really matter here how you call them.

Comment: Ok that does make sense now. And yes I definitely do need a 3d list.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an array of the linked list as follows.. but do not forget to declare when you are going to use the linked list otherwise you will get the nullpointeexception

```
    LinkedList<Integer>[][] ll = new LinkedList[24][24];
    ll[0][0] = new LinkedList<>();
    ll[0][0].addFirst(3);
    System.out.println(ll[0][0].removeFirst());
```

Output : 3

Answer (score 0):

First: You proably can avoid  LinkedList. In Algorithm books, they did not know the ArrayList, Linked List, is more a synonym for dynamic list.
In nearly all cases ArrayList is faster, and especially for 2D arrays, need much less memory.

I personaly when having a fixed grid, with dynamic content, I use arrays:

```
List grid[][];

// init with
grid = new ArrayList[numX][numY];
```

that way i have an grid of object. This uses much less memory.

That way its is much handier when adding objetcs:

```
 List list = grid[i][j];
 if (list == null) {
      list = new ArrayList();
      this.cells[i][j] = list;
 }
 list.add(obj);
```

Comment: @PaulBellora Its a java feature or bug, that you cannt create an array of types Lists, try it out you will be suprised: ArrayList<Integer>[] l = new ArrayList<Integer>[10] does not work.

Comment: You might just want to mention that your solution is influenced by working  with embedded systems where memory is scarce. In general, generic collections classes should almost always be preferred over plain arrays these days.

Comment: @PaulBellora Not for grids of fixed size. Grids are often used for huge data, otherwise a grid would not be used (a brute force search then would be sufficient) But for most task you are right, Generics are prefered. Further its not only memory, it speed to. In this example you gain nothing with (typed) generics.

Answer (score 0):

> I decided to implement this using LinkedList[][], which of
>   course gives me a generic array creation error.
>
> I can't think of a better way of representing the idea of a grid of
>   linked lists. I also understand that using LinkedList[][] would
>   compile but is bad practice as it is untyped.

Simple. To solve those problems just do

```
LinkedList<Integer>[][] grid = (LinkedList<Integer>[][])new LinkedList<?>[5][3];
```